# Can't center this form

Tags: html, css

Ive been looking and looking and I cant center this crud.
Help would be appreciated.

this is the relevant html

```css
.fade-form {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  animation-name: opac;
  animation-delay: 1.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="fade-form">
  <form action=" C:\wamp64\www\data.php" method="post">
   <label for="platenum ">License Plate</label>
   <input type="text" name="platenum " id="platenum">
   <input type="submit" >
  </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: You are missing a dot before your class name for starters

Comment: I thought I was going to get this. Sorry. This was a mistake while making this post. please ignore it.

Comment: ...and closing commas in the markup ;) Anyway, solution below...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was a problem with your HTML itself a closing quote was missing.I'll prefer using `margin:0 auto;` for centering

```css
.fade-form{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align:center;
    animation-name: opac;
    animation-delay: 1.3s;
}
.push-center {
  margin : 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="fade-form">
    <form class='push-center' action="C:\wamp64\www\data.php" method="post">
        <label for="platenum">License Plate</label>
        <input type="text" name="platenum" id="platenum">
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.fade-form{
    background: pink;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align:center;
    animation-name: opac;
    animation-delay: 1.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="fade-form">
    <form action="C:\wamp64\www\data.php" method="post">
        <label for="platenum">License Plate</label>
        <input type="text" name="platenum" id="platenum">
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
```